# Parsing Amazon Electronics Review Apache Pig

Tags: json, parsing, hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

I have loaded Amazon Electronics Reviews dataset(http://jmcauley.ucsd.edu/data/amazon/) 5-core (1,689,188 reviews) in Apache Pig in my cloudera VM

I have followed the other questions asked :-

> [Apache Pig error while dumping Json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36674290/apache-pig-error-while-dumping-json-data)

Review Example

`{ "reviewerID": "A2SUAM1J3GNN3B", "asin": "0000013714", "reviewerName": "J. McDonald", "helpful": [2, 3], "reviewText": "I bought this for my husband who plays the piano. He is having a wonderful time playing these old hymns. The music is at times hard to read because we think the book was published for singing from more than playing from. Great purchase though!", "overall": 5.0, "summary": "Heavenly Highway Hymns", "unixReviewTime": 1252800000, "reviewTime": "09 13, 2009" }`

```
grunt> reviews = LOAD 'amazon/amazon-pro/reviews.json' USING org.apache.pig.builtin.JsonLoader('id:chararray, asin:int, reviewerName: chararray, helpful:(int), reviewText:chararray, overall:float, summary:chararray, time:int, reviewTime:chararray');

grunt> viewReview = LIMIT reviews 1;

grunt> DUMP viewReview;
```

I am getting the following error

```
2016-11-17 08:05:33,797 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig features used in the script: LIMIT
2016-11-17 08:05:35,897 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler - File concatenation threshold: 100 optimistic? false
2016-11-17 08:05:36,531 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size before optimization: 2
2016-11-17 08:05:36,532 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size after optimization: 2
2016-11-17 08:05:37,577 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig script settings are added to the job
2016-11-17 08:05:38,183 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is not set, set to default 0.3
2016-11-17 08:05:38,225 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Setting Parallelism to 1
2016-11-17 08:05:38,230 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - creating jar file Job974442700781595171.jar
2016-11-17 08:05:57,665 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - jar file Job974442700781595171.jar created
2016-11-17 08:05:57,754 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Setting up single store job
2016-11-17 08:05:58,090 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 1 map-reduce job(s) waiting for submission.
2016-11-17 08:05:58,347 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient - Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
2016-11-17 08:05:58,614 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 0% complete
2016-11-17 08:06:00,041 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - dfs.df.interval is deprecated. Instead, use fs.df.interval
2016-11-17 08:06:00,041 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - dfs.max.objects is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.max.objects
2016-11-17 08:06:00,041 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - hadoop.native.lib is deprecated. Instead, use io.native.lib.available
2016-11-17 08:06:00,041 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - dfs.data.dir is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.datanode.data.dir
2016-11-17 08:06:00,041 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - dfs.name.dir is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.name.dir
2016-11-17 08:06:00,041 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2016-11-17 08:06:00,041 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - fs.checkpoint.dir is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.checkpoint.dir
2016-11-17 08:06:00,041 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - dfs.block.size is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.blocksize
2016-11-17 08:06:00,041 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - dfs.access.time.precision is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.accesstime.precision
2016-11-17 08:06:00,042 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - dfs.replication.min is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.replication.min
2016-11-17 08:06:00,042 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - dfs.name.edits.dir is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.edits.dir
2016-11-17 08:06:00,042 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - dfs.replication.considerLoad is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.replication.considerLoad
2016-11-17 08:06:00,042 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - dfs.balance.bandwidthPerSec is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.datanode.balance.bandwidthPerSec
2016-11-17 08:06:00,042 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - dfs.safemode.threshold.pct is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.safemode.threshold-pct
2016-11-17 08:06:00,042 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - dfs.http.address is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.http-address
2016-11-17 08:06:00,042 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - dfs.name.dir.restore is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.name.dir.restore
2016-11-17 08:06:00,042 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - dfs.https.client.keystore.resource is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.client.https.keystore.resource
2016-11-17 08:06:00,042 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - dfs.backup.address is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.backup.address
2016-11-17 08:06:00,042 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - dfs.backup.http.address is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.backup.http-address
2016-11-17 08:06:00,042 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - dfs.permissions is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.permissions.enabled
2016-11-17 08:06:00,042 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - dfs.safemode.extension is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.safemode.extension
2016-11-17 08:06:00,042 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - dfs.datanode.max.xcievers is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.datanode.max.transfer.threads
2016-11-17 08:06:00,042 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - dfs.https.need.client.auth is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.client.https.need-auth
2016-11-17 08:06:00,042 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - dfs.https.address is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.https-address
2016-11-17 08:06:00,043 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - dfs.replication.interval is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.replication.interval
2016-11-17 08:06:00,043 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - fs.checkpoint.edits.dir is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.checkpoint.edits.dir
2016-11-17 08:06:00,043 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - dfs.write.packet.size is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.client-write-packet-size
2016-11-17 08:06:00,043 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - dfs.permissions.supergroup is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.permissions.superusergroup
2016-11-17 08:06:00,043 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - topology.script.number.args is deprecated. Instead, use net.topology.script.number.args
2016-11-17 08:06:00,043 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - dfs.umaskmode is deprecated. Instead, use fs.permissions.umask-mode
2016-11-17 08:06:00,043 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - dfs.secondary.http.address is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.secondary.http-address
2016-11-17 08:06:00,045 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - fs.checkpoint.period is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.checkpoint.period
2016-11-17 08:06:00,045 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - topology.node.switch.mapping.impl is deprecated. Instead, use net.topology.node.switch.mapping.impl
2016-11-17 08:06:00,045 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - io.bytes.per.checksum is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.bytes-per-checksum
2016-11-17 08:06:00,217 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat - Total input paths to process : 1
2016-11-17 08:06:00,270 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths (combined) to process : 11
2016-11-17 08:06:01,755 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - HadoopJobId: job_201611170800_0001
2016-11-17 08:06:01,755 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Processing aliases r,reviews
2016-11-17 08:06:01,755 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - detailed locations: M: reviews[1,10],r[2,4] C:  R: 
2016-11-17 08:06:01,755 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - More information at: http://localhost.localdomain:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201611170800_0001
2016-11-17 08:09:30,985 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 50% complete
2016-11-17 08:09:31,500 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - job job_201611170800_0001 has failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
2016-11-17 08:09:31,538 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 100% complete
2016-11-17 08:09:31,596 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backed error: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Current token (VALUE_STRING) not numeric, can not use numeric value accessors
 at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@67de0c09; line: 1, column: 43]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1291)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportError(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:385)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonNumericParserBase._parseNumericValue(JsonNumericParserBase.java:399)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonNumericParserBase.getIntValue(JsonNumericParserBase.java:254)
    at org.apache.pig.builtin.JsonLoader.readField(JsonLoader.java:189)
    at org.apache.pig.builtin.JsonLoader.getNext(JsonLoader.java:157)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigRecordReader.nextKeyValue(PigRecordReader.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:483)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.MapContextImpl.nextKeyValue(MapContextImpl.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.map
2016-11-17 08:09:31,597 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce job(s) failed!
2016-11-17 08:09:31,602 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - Script Statistics: 

HadoopVersion   PigVersion  UserId  StartedAt   FinishedAt  Features
2.0.0-cdh4.7.0  0.11.0-cdh4.7.0 cloudera    2016-11-17 08:05:37 2016-11-17 08:09:31 LIMIT

Failed!

Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
job_201611170800_0001   r,reviews       Message: Job failed!    

Input(s):
Failed to read data from "hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020/user/cloudera/amazon/amazon-pro/reviews.json"

Output(s):

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
job_201611170800_0001   ->  null,
null


2016-11-17 08:09:31,602 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Failed!
2016-11-17 08:09:31,635 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias r
Details at logfile: /home/cloudera/pig_1479349681179.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a problem with your schema definition for `helpful`. Related to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076583/pig-default-jsonloader-schema-issue#21084300) it should look like something like this:

```
..., helpful:{t:(score:int)}, ...
```

Comment: I am querying for tuple values inside a bag. Any Idea on this. reviewHelpPercent = FOREACH reviews GENERATE asin, helpful, (double)helpful.$0/helpful.$1 * 100 AS helpPercent, reviewTime;

Answer (score 0):

```
reviews = LOAD '/user/cloudera/review.json' USING org.apache.pig.builtin.JsonLoader('reviewerID:chararray, asin:chararray,reviewerName: chararray, helpful:{t:(score:int)}, reviewText:chararray, overall:chararray, summary:chararray, Time:chararray, reviewTime:chararray');

DUMP reviews;
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/24234474)